# Ubuntu 16.04.1 : shutdown/reboot stuck on "[ok] stopped thermal daemon service"

Tags: shutdown, reboot

As title says, 3 out of 5 times I shutdown my ubuntu 16.04.1 it always stuck on "[ok] stop thermal daemon service".

My hardware :

- Dell vostro 5459
- Samsung 850 EVO 250 GB
- I5 6200U
- 8GB DDR3

This seems to happened since a month ago after I dual boot windows and Ubuntu.

This thing seems to be triggered if I do anything with my mysql database (installed locally).

If I start my ubuntu and just do some browsing with chrome and mozilla, doing some document works with libreoffice. The problem doesn't happen.

I've made the windows drive to not automatically mount. but it makes no difference.

I've googled for answer, yet no solution really works.

Thank you for any reply or suggestions.

*english is not my native language so please pardon me for any mistakes

Comment: "[ok] stop thermal daemon service" means the thermal daemon service was shutdown correctly and your system is hanging on the _next_ task. Do you have any more information about what that might be? How long are you usually waiting before giving up? It _should_ timeout eventually and provide you with some kind of meaningful error message.

Comment: I've waited for an hour one time. Nothing happens. No error is given. the only solution i've found so far is by holding my power button for a few seconds (hard restart) until my laptop turns off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fix for my problem.

*I don't know why the last time I try to wait it out it took more than an hour to shutdown.

What I did was I recorded the shutdown process with my phone in Slow-mo Mode.

Like before, it stucks at

```
[ok] stopped thermal daemon service
```

After around 10 minutes, I see something like this

```
[ok] stopped thermal daemon service 
[ok] stopped mysql community server
```

right before a bunch of text very quickly fill the screen and my laptop shuts down.

So the problem turns out that mysql community server is not shutting down on it's own. but even after the timeout (10 minutes) ran out, **it doesn't give me a single error or anything**.

Here's the solution

type the following in terminal

```
 systemctl show mysql
```

it will return the location of mysql service configuration in one of the lines. for example mine says

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
```

edit the file (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service) find a line that contain the word "timeout". change the value.

```
TimeoutSec=600
```

to

```
TimeoutSec=5
```

What this does is change the timeout of mysql community server from 10 minutes to 5 seconds, if stopping/starting the service took more than the timeout value, it will force close/stop the service. Making my ubuntu shuts down faster.