# Ubuntu stuck on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS after a long time with Windows. Now I can't shutdown or restart Ubuntu from the GUI reliably.

I've seen some posts about grub and haven't found anything useful.  But, it shuts down properly when I perform

```
sudo shutdown -v -h now
```

After that, subsequent shutdowns execute correctly from the GUI until I install a new application through the terminal.

NOTE: Windows 10 was installed first, then the Ubuntu was installed.

Comment: would a fresh install be out of place to see if the issue goes away?

Comment: Why install 14.04, when 16.04.1 is the current LTS distribution at https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop ?

Comment: Well my friend told me that 16,04 is less stable than 14.04? And I failed to install it through USB. When I select try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu both of them stuck on the loading screen just like the problem with shutdown. Something is wrong I can feel it :)) at Last I'm gonna have to wipe all drive and put only Ubuntu on it %)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was solved by installing Nvidia graphics card drivers (the supported version - that's important). On some of new computers driver problems occur. Luckily I was able to figure it out somehow and installed the driver. Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these boot parameters, as ACPI and APM often can be problematic.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

to change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"
```

then save the file and exit gedit.

Then, do

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modules
```

and add

```
apm power_off=1
```

and save the file. Then do

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot. Should that not resolve the issue, please record the shutdown using your smartphone in slo mo mode a la [Ubuntu 16.04.1 : shutdown/reboot stuck on "[ok] stopped thermal daemon service"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832491/ubuntu-16-04-1-shutdown-reboot-stuck-on-ok-stopped-thermal-daemon-service?rq=1)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but there is nothing like that when shutting down, my lines end on "will now halt"  except for that line every line is "OK". I mean there is nothing to record. Also I tried your method, restarted through terminal no problems since. I installed an application and it does not shutdown through the gui, again.

Comment: I found the problem!! I just deleted the app "guake" and it shuts down correctly. I believe it was waiting to close guake but fails so. I like guake is there a solution :)

Comment: So do I ! Then,  please edit your question and note what you have done since you wrote it,  and that you found a guake inspired shutdown failure. Reinstall guake and see if problem returns. Also please change title to add "because of guake"  at end. I will look for a solution, but this is progress !